# Implementing infinite scroll in backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

Hi how should I implement infinite scroll in back-end. I am using node.js. Should I just remember last item's id and query for items that come after it? Or there is another way to accomplish it?

Comment: Questions posted on SO should point to a specific problem, and the poster should always show a bit of effort and code. What you're asking can't have a good answer, and will be nearly impossible to help someone else in the future. Still, to answer your question, you can get the first 5 items from the database, and then remeber where you remained to continue onto the next page of 5 items, and so on, this way you're creating a pagination, which is exactly what you need. You just need to always set the page number as a parameter on your API endpoint.

Comment: If you want to do an infinite scrolling API, you sound be using the query string? the URL should look like this `https://api.app.com/users?offset=10`, and then you can start fetching data with the offset filter within your database, and don't forget you limit you API resource.

Comment: For people coming here in the future: Value based it better approach, and you have to remember it in the client side, try not to have any session data in the server side, please read this article: https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/art-pagination-offset-vs-value-based-paging/